# Center Text horizontally through out multiple <td> in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table that is a timetable.
What I want is if there are two or more of the same tasks come after each other for the border between to go. (This I have done). Also i want the text to be centered in the middle of the table.

See Example for clarification:

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td")
for (var o = 0; o < tds.length; o++) {
  if ($(tds[o]).next().html() === $(tds[o]).html() && $(tds[o]).prev().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
    $(tds[o]).css("borderRight", "none");
    $(tds[o]).css("borderLeft", "none");
  } else if ($(tds[o]).next().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
    $(tds[o]).css("borderRight", "none");
  } else if ($(tds[o]).prev().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
    $(tds[o]).css("borderLeft", "none");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1:00</th>
      <th>2:00</th>
      <th>3:00</th>
      <th>4:00</th>
      <th>5:00</th>
      <th>6:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sleep</td>//Should Only be one "Sleep" and it should be centered through all the "Sleep td"
      <td>Sleep</td>
      <td>Sleep</td>
      <td>Sleep</td>
      <td>Sleep</td>
      <td>Wake Up</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're looking for `colspan`

Comment: I strongly recommend AGAINST using o as your incrementor in your function - wayyyyy  too easy to read it later (or in SO) as a zero - ie: tds[o] vs tds[0] - obvious when you see it side by side but when you are reading it out of context or trying to debug it is to easy to see tds[o] and think its referencing the first td (ie index[0]). Just My 0pinion. .... see what I did  there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `colspan`.

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td")
    for (var o = 0; o < tds.length; o++) {
            if ($(tds[o]).next().html() === $(tds[o]).html() && $(tds[o]).prev().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
                $(tds[o]).css("borderRight", "none");
                $(tds[o]).css("borderLeft", "none");
            } else if ($(tds[o]).next().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
                $(tds[o]).css("borderRight", "none");
            } else if ($(tds[o]).prev().html() === $(tds[o]).html()) {
                $(tds[o]).css("borderLeft", "none");
            }
        }
```

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        border: 2px solid grey;
        padding: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    th {
        border: 2px solid grey;
        padding: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1:00</th>
            <th>2:00</th>
            <th>3:00</th>
            <th>4:00</th>
            <th>5:00</th>
            <th>6:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Sleep</td> //Should Only be one "Sleep" and it should be centered through all the "Sleep td"        
            <td>Wake Up</td>            

        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all of the

```
<td>Sleep</td>
```

And put in:-

```
<td colspan="5">Sleep</td>
```